# The code gives Connection Error error after a while

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I get a "Connection Error" error while capturing data. It works fine for a while then gives error, how can I overcome this error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.example.com"
for page in range(0,951,50):
    new_url = url +page + "&pagingSize=50" 
    r = requests.get(new_url)            
    source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")               
    content = source.select('tr.searchResultsItem:not(.nativeAd, .classicNativeAd)')
    print(content)
```

**When I get this error, I want it to wait for a while and continue where it left off**

Error:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')"))
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message.  Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: It's possible that you are being throttled by the service you're connecting to. Hard to tell without an example and without the full error message

Comment: I added the error to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround connection resets (and other networking problems) by implementing retries. Basically, you can tell requests to automatically retry if a problem occurs.

Here's how you can do it:

```py
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

session = requests.Session()

# in case of error, retry at most 3 times, waiting
# at least half a second between each retry
retry = Retry(total=3, backoff_factor=0.5)  

adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)
```

Then, instead of:

```py
r = requests.get(new_url)
```

you can use:

```py
r = session.get(new_url)
```

See also the documentation for [`Retry`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.retry.Retry) for a full overview of the scenarios it supports.